# Swift: using reference types with GCD

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have this recursive function that waits until an Image is loaded.
However, it does not function properly.
The UIImageView is never updated.

(The image parameter is a field of a class type, and being downloaded using Alamofire)

Since UIImage is a reference type, what is the error?

```
func waitForImage(image: UIImage?, imageName: String, imageView: UIImageView, waitTimeInSec: Double = 0.5, repeatCount: Int = 0) {
    let maxWaits = 10

    if image != nil {
        imageView.image = image
    }
    else {
        if repeatCount > maxWaits {
            return
        }

        delay(waitTimeInSec) {
            self.waitForImage(image, imageName: imageName, imageView: imageView, 
                      waitTimeInSec: waitTimeInSec, repeatCount: repeatCount + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Where **delay** is defined as:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
  dispatch_after(
    dispatch_time(
        DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
        Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    ),
    dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Here is how I call the function:

```
waitForImage(item.owner.picture, imageName: "Owner's Avatar, \(item.owner.ID)", imageView: ivAvatar)
```

Comment: Where is the `image` supposed to come from?

Comment: @jtbandes It is a field of a class. I added a sample call to make it more clear.

Comment: What do you try to achieve by this function? Maybe there are cleaner ways like using timer?

Comment: But it's not a field of a class, it's just a parameter passed to your function.

Comment: @jtbandes Isn't the parameter a reference to the class field?

Comment: Nope! It's a reference to the image, and the class field (property / ivar) is also a reference to the same image, but they aren't references to each other.

Comment: @jtbandes Changing the signature to pass my class type fixes it, but now it is not generic. I would like to make it work for any class.

Comment: have you tried dispatching to the main queue? wrapping `imageView.image = image` inside like this `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){ imageView.image = image }`

Comment: @MikeG Since *delay* dispatches to the main queue already, why would this be necessary?

Comment: 99% chance its not necessary but GCD works in mysterious ways so its certainly worth a try before potentially wasting hours

Comment: @MikeG No, it did not fix it. I just need a **holder** for the UIImage, as jtbandes suggested . Passing it directly, loses the association to my class field. However, I want this to be generic...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a reference to the image, I believe you want a reference to a reference to an image which you can get by making `image` and inout argument. So maybe something like:

`func waitForImage(inout image: UIImage?, imageName: String, imageView: UIImageView, waitTimeInSec: Double = 0.5, repeatCount: Int = 0)`

And call it like:

`waitForImage(&item.owner.picture, imageName: "Owner's Avatar, \(item.owner.ID)", imageView: ivAvatar)`

---

After thinking about it a bit more, an alternative approach that would still provide a generic solution like you want would be to create a protocol like:

```
protocol ImageProvider {
    var providedImage: UIImage? { get }
}
```

And let make that item.owner class conform to it. Then tweak `waitForImage`:

```
func waitForImage(imageProvider: ImageProvider, imageName: String, imageView: UIImageView, waitTimeInSec: Double = 0.5, repeatCount: Int = 0) {
    let maxWaits = 10

    if imageProvider.providedImage != nil {
        imageView.image = imageProvider.providedImage
    }
    else {
        if repeatCount <= maxWaits {
            delay(waitTimeInSec) {
                self.waitForImage(imageProvider, imageName: imageName, imageView: imageView,
                      waitTimeInSec: waitTimeInSec, repeatCount: repeatCount + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like:

`waitForImage(item.owner, imageName: "Owner's Avatar, \(item.owner.ID)", imageView: ivAvatar)`

Comment: I have already tried the `inout` approach, but it does not work.